# How does iTunes Detect DFU mode and can i alter it to open up another program instead on macOS

Tags: ios, macos

Since the release of Checkm8, a powerful exploit for A5-A11 devices, a jailbreak has been released called Checkra1n. Checkra1n has a CLI version, which will listen and wait for the device to enter DFU mode so it can run and jailbreak (or in my case, re-enable the jailbreak if my device hangs or needs to be rebooted - Since this is a tethered exploit, it needs to be run on reboot).

Is there a way to automate when the computer detects DFU, to run the CLI of checkra1n and jailbreak it?

This is for macOS.

Answer (score 0):

Both the checkra1n CLI and GUI (for MacOS) walk the user through getting to DFU, and they detect and proceed automatically after that.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there’s a function which only detects a DFU device when it is running. However (this is my guest), that function is always running in the background until a device is detected, it won’t print anything to let you know it’s waiting for a DFU device.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it what the problem open checkra1n cli and connect in DFU mode!!